# AWS: Multiple EC2 Instance and single RDS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-rds

How to manage AWS multiple instances... and what is the use of different options available while we enter into "AWS Console"... Like: US East (N. Virginia), US West (Oregon) and US West (N. California) etc...

What I understood is, we can created multiple instances with same configuration (Deploy same web pages, services on all instances - right?) and single RDS Instance... All these EC2 instance will point to single RDS instance - right? (Not sure here...)

**As a result we have 3 EC2 instances**

1. Instance_1: US East (N. Virginia)
2. Instance_2: US West (Oregon) and
3. Instance_3: US West (N. California)

All above instances will point to single "RDS Instance" - right? and in DNS resolving list we will add name record pointing to different IP address (Single DNS for above 3 Instance IP Address)

Just want to know is this correct understanding? This is the key benefit of AWS services - Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Having 3 Web Server - Instance in 3 different regions and all the three connected to a single RDS Instance is good but having the Web Server and RDS Instance in the Same Region i.e. like US East (N.Virginia) is always good to start for the obvious reasons of latency.

I suggest you to start with selection of a region, launch Web Server and RDS instance in the same region and AZ. Later on the step would be concentrate on the HA for the RDS like ( Multi-AZ ).

Based on your question, I think you need a understanding of the Regions.

**Region :** 
Regions are geographical locations where the Amazon Data center are located. Every region would have option run the services like EC2, S3, RDS, VPC etc. independently.

**AZ - Availability Zone :**
AZs are more like Sub Data Centers - inside each region which has independent - power, cooling and network. Every Region has different number of AZs example : US East - Virginia has 5 but US West - N. California has 3 etc.

PS : You question isn't clear and very broad; So the answer is generic.

Comment: Again thank you for response... Really want to understand AWS Eco System.. 

I am very much new with this AWS, Server and Deployment stuff... Anyway no excuse - main worry for my client is "speed up the connection" between Adroid/iOS apps to server. If user sitting @ EAST COAST and tries to connect to server then if we have Instance in "EAST COAST" then it helps...